# Is there a way to update database table in JPQL with value from a Map?

Tags: java, jpql, entitymanager

Assume, I have a map:

```
Map<Long, String> idsToValue = new HashMap<Long, String>();
idsToValue.put(1L, "New Value 1");
idsToValue.put(3L, "New Value 3");
```

And column in database:

```
ID   VALUE          ...some other columns
1    "old value 1"  ...
2    "old value 2"  ...
3    "old value 3"  ...
```

Is there a way to update database rows with values from a Map, where ID is Map's key, and VALUE is Map's value, through one request to database?

Something like:

```
EntityManager.createquery("update MyColumn set VALUE =:idsToValue.value where ID =:idsToValue.key").setParameters("idsToValue", idsToValue).executeUpdate();
```

Comment: do you want this for performance reasons, (i.e. bulk update), or just for ease of use? also, what database do you have?

Comment: performance reasons, Oracle/Hibernate (but I don't want to use vendor specific stuff, and stick to JPQL only, if that's possible)